# Does Netty 4.0.43 support Websockets RFC 6455?

Tags: websocket, netty

Does `Netty 4.0.43` support `Websockets RFC 6455`?

Official docs say about `Hybi-10` and mentioning about `Hybi-17`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Netty supports WebSockets RFC6455 since a long time.